# Lua: How to retrieve a decimal number from string?

Tags: lua

I have the following code in Lua:

```
function getSystemLoad()
   local file = io.popen('./check_cpu.pl')
   local value = file:read('*l')
   file:close()
   return value 
end
```

The output of this function could be: **CPU OK: 0.51%**
or **CPU WARNING: 76.5%**

I need this function to return just a decimal number, in these cases **0.51** or **76.5**

Comment: `return tonumber(value:match"([%d.]+)%%")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Better make that '(%d+%.%d+)%%' to not match multiple dots, even if in this particular case apparently this cannot happen.

Comment: @tonypdmtr - this does not work for `CPU WARNING: 100%`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Right, so you need: '(%d+%.?%d+)%%'

Comment: And to match even single digits, use: '(%d-%.?%d+)%%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local function extractDecimalFrom( str )
  local t = {}
  for i in string.gmatch( str, "[0-9]+%.[0-9]+" ) do
    t[#t+1] = tonumber(i)
  end
  return t
end

local s = "CPU OK: 0.51% or CPU WARNING: 76.5%"

local extractedDecimals = extractDecimalFrom( s )

for i=1, #extractedDecimals do
  print(extractedDecimals[i])
end
```

Comment: References:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin
https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/data/luaString/index.html#patterns

Comment: Thank you. I need this function to return a decimal not to print it to stdout. I've done it myself using your suggestion, it works but the code looks a bit bulky because I'm very new to Lua. Could you plz offer a short option for my function to return decimal?

Comment: I have modified the code to wrap it in a function which will now only return the first decimal it finds. Considering your expected input will only contain one decimal, it should work for you. You could simply call return with the gmatch inside the tonumber and reduce it further.

Comment: @Matt W the dot should be escaped (`%.`) because it is a special character (matches anything).

Comment: I've just tidied up my code and made it return a table of found numbers so that all numbers in the string will be returned.